# Deletes from MySQL not reflecting in Debezium

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, apache-kafka, debezium

I've configured CDC from MySQL to Elasticsearch, Inserts, and Updates are working but Deletes aren't. I've enabled "delete.enabled": "true" and "behavior.on.null.values": "delete", but still it isn't working. Even after I delete data from MySQL, it stays in Elasticsearch

MySQL Connector config :

```
"config": {
    "connector.class": "io.debezium.connector.mysql.MySqlConnector",
    "database.allowPublicKeyRetrieval": "true",
    "database.user": "reader",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "database.history.kafka.bootstrap.servers": "X.X.X.X:9092",
    "database.history.kafka.topic": "schema-changes.mysql",
    "database.server.name": "search_ai",
    "schema.include.list": "search_ai",
    "database.port": "3306",
    "tombstones.on.delete": "false",
    "delete.enabled": "true",
    "database.hostname": "sourcesql",
    "database.password": "xxxx",
    "name": "mysql_test",
    "table.include.list": "search_ai.*"
  },
```

Elasticsearch Connector config:

```
 "config": {
    "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.elasticsearch.ElasticsearchSinkConnector",
    "type.name": "lab",
    "behavior.on.null.values": "delete",
    "transforms.unwrap.delete.handling.mode": "rewrite",
    "transforms.extractKey.field": "ID",
    "tasks.max": "1",
    "topics": "search_ai.search_ai.lab_flat",
    "transforms.InsertKey.fields": "ID",
    "transforms": "unwrap,key,InsertKey,extractKey",
    "key.ignore": "false",
    "transforms.extractKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.key.field": "ID",
    "transforms.key.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ExtractField$Key",
    "transforms.unwrap.drop.tombstones": "false",
    "name": "es_lab",
    "transforms.unwrap.type": "io.debezium.transforms.ExtractNewRecordState",
    "connection.url": "http://X.X.X.X:9200",
    "transforms.InsertKey.type": "org.apache.kafka.connect.transforms.ValueToKey"
  },
```

Comment: What value and key converters are you using?

Comment: Did you consume the Debezium-produced data? Are you seeing null values that cause deletes in Elasticsearch? Did you create a simpler example with the Elasticsearch sink config only and your own producer where deletes did work?

Comment: Yes, I'm seeing before : {ID:2,data:...} and after : null in messages. I tried different approaches with Elasticsearch sink, but can't get deletes to work.

Comment: Your keys are Structs, not document ids? I'm not sure that works with Elasticsearch. Also, have you tried adjusting `tombstones.on.delete`?